# Is it important to specify file mode('w', 'r', 'a') when opening a file? What happens when you don't?

Tags: python, file

Hi I'm a beginner programmer and I recently started writing some code. I found out that when opening files, you can specify the file mode or the operation you want to do with the file.

For example: `with open(file.txt, 'r') as file:`

I tried experimenting and found out that if I just do `with open(file.txt) as file:` I can still do the things I want to do with the file which is read its contents into memory.

My question then are:

1. Is it really important to specify the file mode when accessing/opening it?
2. Is it bad if I don't specify?
3. Does not specifying only work with python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'r'` is the default. It is a matter of taste if you explicitly use it. All other modes require explicit use.

Comment: In case of doubt, read [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) rather than trying to experiment. It starts with `open(file, mode='r', buffering=- 1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)` and says a bit further "mode is an optional string that specifies the mode in which the file is opened. It defaults to 'r' which means open for reading in text mode."

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), the `mode` argument _is an optional string that specifies the mode in which the file is opened. It defaults to 'r' which means open for reading in text mode._ So, 1: no it's not important, you can leave it out, and it will open the file for reading; 2: no, it's reasonable to let it default to `r` if you're only reading it anyway; 3: no matter what programming language is used, an OS function call (e.g. win32's `CreateFileA`) will be made to open the file, and that OS function needs to know what mode to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Mendrezzzzz it's nice that you starting programming

1. No if you just want to read it it is not needed, because "r" is default, but it makes it more readable, so that if you or someone else later is reading your Code immediately knows which mode this file is opened
2. For Readability in my opinion yes. But it doesn't break your Code so practically no. But please consider the readability for the future you or person who is reading your code
3. Well this is tricky there are many languages, where you have to give a Mode for a Filestream or where you have to Use completely different Classes for the different Modes (Java), but there sure are other languages like python making Reading the default mode (I don't know every language)

I hope this helps you. I would recommend to learn also Coding Conventions if you want really to learn programming.

Good Python tutorial https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter1/

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the clear answers. I tried reading the documentation but  the python documentation site is... well... not very beginner friendly. I almost got a headache trying to understand the cryptic information found on the site. I'm sorry for asking such a lame question. I'll work more on reading and understanding documentation so that I won't be asking questions like these next time. Thank you so much though! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mendrezzzzz Well I am not so good with the SO Guidelines, but the Question is on my opinion totally fine, You are a beginner and that was a good question. It wasn't technically a programming problem but it is important (especially if you work in a team) to follow conventions. Don't let yourself down and continue your journey in Coding :)